# Would you say "I would like to express my worries ON/IN or ABOUT"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prepositions, difference, verbs

I know ABOUT is way more common but could you also use: ON? I asked ChatGPT (sorry) this same question and it gave me the following answer:

*"I would like to express my worries on the current economic situation." (Specific topic)
"I would like to express my worries in this difficult time." (Situation or circumstance)
So, if you're expressing worries about a particular topic, you would say "I would like to express my worries on [topic]." If you're expressing worries about a situation or circumstance, you would say "I would like to express my worries in [situation or circumstance]."*

Thanks!

Comment: The ChatGPT answer means that if you are expressing worries at a certain time or in certain circumstances you might use "in". This has nothing to do with the topic your worries are about. For instance if there's a war on, you might say "I would like to express my worries in this time of war". If you're in a bar, you might say "I would like to express my worries in this bar". About is also fine for the topic.

Comment: Your usage is "understandable", in both senses. 1) We know what you *mean*, and 2) it's obvious you're basing your "creative usage" on similar expressions like *These are my opinions / thoughts / feelings / views / ... **on** the matter*. But native speakers effectively *never*  use ***on*** after ***worries*** in such contexts, so I suggest you give it up. Or switch to *I have **concerns** on the matter* (not great, imho, but ***on*** sounds tolerable there).